# XDSOFT JQPlugin -> DateTimePicker: How to disable previous days?

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins, datepicker

I'm currently using datetimepicker plugin from xdsoft.net and i'm trying to validate the selected days by disabling the previous days from the present day.

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    minDate: "1",
});
```

Simple answer